# PrimeFaces dataTable column issue

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee-6

[image]

I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 version.

Please may I know the reason for display table like this?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: you can change the width of the column, by adding the "width=100" to the `<p:column>`

Comment: Thank you very much. "width=100"